# A cron job that creates objects - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on an event app, that showcases the events near my area.

A Boolean `is_weekly_event` is set for each entry.

If it is set to true I need to show that event in my app every week on the same data and time.

Therefore, I need to write a cron job, that re-creates this event every time it passes it's end_time, for the same time next week!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a rake task and add it to cronjob, http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/systems/automation.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to add cron job. I have used this in one of my projects and works very fine.

You can define rake tasks in lib/ and in your schedule.rb file which will be generated when you will do whenervize your project.

```
every 3.hours do # 1.minute 1.day 1.week 1.month 1.year is also supported
  # your task here
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  # your task here
end
```

After finishing all you need is to update your crontab file for your machine using this command.

```
$ whenever --update-crontab
```

Note - just a take care to load proper environment(dev, prod) for the rake tasks, it took me hard to find out when i was trying to run the cron.

Thanks